# Changing Mobile Application SDK

Tags: mobile, sdk

If i develop a mobile application using a specific BaaS SDK  like parse.  later on i decide to move to another BaaS.
Will the user need to remove and then install the app. Or i can offer the new application as an update?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding moving from Parse to another BaaS I know about apiOmat which lets you import all your data from Parse (see [this blog post](http://www.apiomat.com/migrate-from-parse-to-apiomat/)). Then you upload your updated app to the app store / play store and the user only needs to update the app - no removing and reinstalling necessary. Have a look in the official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/index.html).